# Drill down chart in angular

Tags: angularjs, charts, drilldown

I want to have a column chart in my angular app that could be drilled down to a line chart. I think the main problem is to be able to handle click event on each column that I could not find it `highchart` nor `angular-chart`. Can you tell me a way to construct such thing?

Comment: Is it the one http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/Cp73s/??

Comment: I see nothing in this link :-?

Answer (score 6):

ZingChart has an Angular directive that works well with your use case. You can use the directive with ZingChart's internal events to bind to just about anything on the chart :

```
zingchart.node_click = function(p) {
  ....
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/mschultz/ck84wjce/

Angular Directive: https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-AngularJS

Docs : http://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/api-events/

It can also perform drilldowns fairly easily across different types of charts: http://www.zingchart.com/blog/2014/09/02/chart-drilldown-interactive-feature/

If you need any help, feel free to reach out - I work for the ZingChart team!

Comment: Is it free to use? Is it open source?

Comment: It is not open source, but it is free to use with the watermark. We do offer paid packages with support and without the watermark for commercial and enterprise use as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this page](https://canvasjs.com/angular-charts/drilldown-chart/) for an example on Angular Drill Down chart using CanvasJS Angular Chart. It also includes angular source code or download angular sample from [download page](https://canvasjs.com/download-html5-charting-graphing-library/).

Check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drilldown-chart) for a simple example.
[image: Angular Drill Down Chart]